# R replacing values of a column with those of other column's rows

Tags: r, replace

For the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("July Doe", "John Doe", NA, "Jane Doe"), 
                 age = c(NA, NA, NA, 43), 
                 name1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "John Doe"), 
                 age1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 37), 
                 name2 = c(NA, NA, "July Doe", NA),
                 age2 = c(NA, NA, 7, NA))
```

which provides:

```
          name age    name1 age1    name2 age2
    1 July Doe  NA     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
    2 John Doe  NA     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
    3     <NA>  NA     <NA>   NA July Doe    7
    4 Jane Doe  43 John Doe   37     <NA>   NA
```

I need to change `age` to the corresponding `age1` or `age2` when `name` matches with either `name1` or `name2`.

So far, I've come up with this (with no luck).

```
df$age <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(df$age), ifelse(df$name %in% df$name1,
                          as.integer(df$age1), as.integer(df$age)), as.integer(df$age)))
```

If any advanced R user can explain, it'd be eternally grateful. I'd like to keep remaining NA and have something like:

```
          name age    name1 age1    name2 age2
    1 July Doe   7     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
    2 John Doe  37     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
    3     <NA>  NA     <NA>   NA July Doe    7
    4 Jane Doe  43 John Doe   37     <NA>   NA
```

Then I can handle dropping rows with only NAs and the columns I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
within(df,age[is.na(age)] <- c(age1,age2)[match(name[is.na(age)],c(as.character(name1),as.character(name2)))]);
##       name age    name1 age1    name2 age2
## 1 July Doe   7     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
## 2 John Doe  37     <NA>   NA     <NA>   NA
## 3     <NA>  NA     <NA>   NA July Doe    7
## 4 Jane Doe  43 John Doe   37     <NA>   NA
```

The reason why your code is not working is that in the inner `ifelse()`, you're testing if `name` matches *anywhere* within `name1`, but the selected value will end up coming from the index of `name`, rather than the index of the matching value in `name1`.

Comment: Thank you both (bgoldst and nicola)!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:3,function(x) setNames(df[(2*x-1):(2*x)],c("name","age"))))
res$age<-ave(res$age,res$name,FUN=function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
do.call(cbind,split(res,(seq_len(nrow(res))-1) %/% (nrow(res)/3)))      
#    0.name 0.age   1.name 1.age   2.name 2.age
#1 July Doe     7     <NA>    NA     <NA>    NA
#2 John Doe    37     <NA>    NA     <NA>    NA
#3     <NA>    NA     <NA>    NA July Doe     7
#4 Jane Doe    43 John Doe    37     <NA>    NA
```

In short: first you create a `data.frame` with just two columns (`name` and `age`) in such a way you can fill the missing `NA`. At the end, you revert to the original format.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna stay with the ifelse...

```
df$age <- ifelse(!is.na(df$age1[match(df$name, df$name1)]), 
                 df$age1[match(df$name, df$name1)],  
                 df$age2[match(df$name, df$name2)])
```